# Remove object by array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I want to remove object from array that matches the `id` from array, like this one

```
var report = [{ id:1, title: "title 1"},{ id:2, title: "title 2"},{ id:3, title: "title 3"},{ id:4, title: "title 4"},{ id:5, title: "title 5"}];
var array = [1,2,3];
```

I just want to remove an object that matches in an array. The result that I expected is like

```
var report = [{ id:4, title: "title 4"},{ id:5, title: "title 5"}];
```

I have used `.splice.` method on `.forEach` but it seems doesn't work so well.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please show how you actually have used `splice`.

Comment: `report.forEach(function(item,index,object){
   for(var i ; array.length <=0;i++) {
      if(array[i] === item.id) {
         object.splice(index,1);
      }
   }
})`

Comment: ^^??? There's no `splice` in that example. Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `indexOf()`

```js
var report = [{ id:1, title: "title 1"},{ id:2, title: "title 2"},{ id:3, title: "title 3"},{ id:4, title: "title 4"},{ id:5, title: "title 5"}];
var array = [1,2,3];

var result = report.filter(function(e) {
  return array.indexOf(e.id) == -1;
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var report = [{ id:1, title: "title 1"},{ id:2, title: "title 2"},{ id:3, title:"title 3"},{ id:4, title: "title 4"},{ id:5, title: "title 5"}];
var array = [1,2,3];

var newReport = report.filter(function(item){
  return array.indexOf(item.id) == -1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `.splice()` (but without `.forEach()`)

```js
var report = [
  { id: 1, title: "title 1" },
  { id: 2, title: "title 2" },
  { id: 3, title: "title 3" },
  { id: 4, title: "title 4" },
  { id: 5, title: "title 5" }
];
var array = [1, 2, 3];

// "walk" backwards to circumvent the problem of the changing length because of .splice()
for (var i = (report.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
  if (array.indexOf(report[i].id) > -1) {
    report.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(report);
```